# Is there a way to combine files in an http request?

Tags: javascript, httprequest, tar

[My website](https://www.whereisroadster.com) is taking longer to load than is optimal because it requests a lot of small files, and those small files eventually take up a lot of requests. The ones I have the most control over are a number of data files which will always be loaded, but having them as separate files makes the process of generating them easier. Is there a way that I could put one HTTP request to a (tar?) file, and then process that efficiently with JavaScript? This is the function that I am using right now to read in the data files. What I would really like is a way to request one file that can be easily parsed. The file structure is very simple, just a collection of 4 byte floats, in a repeating pattern. I suppose I could, and I might, combine them in to a slightly more complex data structure, but if there's a way to just combine all of these files and read it in JavaScript I would love to se it!

Also of some note is some small icon files, I have a dozen or so of those that I would love to do the same thing, combine in to a single file and just load that one file.

```
function loadBinaryFloatArray(url, convertFunction,variable_name, onLoaded) {
    
    var mRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    mRequest.open('GET', url);
    mRequest.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

    mRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {

            // Get bytes
            var buffer = this.response;
            var dataview = new DataView(buffer);

            // Create buffer (4 bytes / float)
            var mFloatArray = new Float64Array(buffer.byteLength / 8);

            // Copy floats
            for (var i = 0; i < mFloatArray.length; i++) 
            {
                mFloatArray[i] = dataview.getFloat64(i * 8,true); // At every 8th byte
            }
            
            onLoaded(convertFunction(Array.prototype.slice.call(mFloatArray)),variable_name)
        }
    };
    mRequest.send();
}
```

Comment: `but if there's a way to just combine all of these files and read it` - of course you can do that on the server side - but you haven't mentioned what you're running as far as the http server is concerned or what (scripting) languages you can use on your server - really - it's trivial to do this on the server

Comment: could you trial using base64 encoded inline images for all the small icon files? - https://www.base64-image.de/tutorial

Comment: Will this really improve performance? We have wide support of gzip and http/2 with multiplexing requests nowadays.

Comment: I'd disagree with your first sentence. I just ran Google Lighthouse on your app and there are a bunch of optimizations you can do that don't involve mucking with combining requests or whatever. For example, the site loads 7 seconds of unused JavaScript! Also, there's 50 seconds of JavaScript execution time after it loads. I recommend working down the list of Google Lighthouse recommendations and that should get you a lot of the way there.

Comment: Will look at Google Lighthouse then. The website is 100% static, so no server scripting allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the simplest things for your icons would be to use a spritemap.

That being said. This is normally not a thing you should do: Join files on the server, because then you have to resend this HUGE request if it fails.

I also took a look at your website. For me it loads pretty fast. The major problem is that you keep requesting the same image (WhereIsRoadster.png) over and over again, which is probably the thing slowing your website down. Or it might also be down to your internet connection. Without more details, there is not much more I can tell you.